# Modal handle outside click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a modal in my React application and I'm closing modal, when user clicks out of it. The functionality is below:

```
handleOutsideClick = (evt) => {
    const { handleClose } = this.props

    if(!_isNull(this.modal)) {
        if(!this.modal.contains(evt.target)) {
            handleClose()
        }
    }
}
```

The modal div has `ref={ node => (this.modal = node) }` of course. Now I have a dynamic form inside the modal: user adds values, they are visualised like "chips" and they can be deleted ... but here comes the problem ... if I delete some chip by clicking on it, it is removed from the DOM and the modal closes, because the condition `!this.modal.contains(evt.target)` evaluates to `true`. How can I solve this problem?

My modal code is here:

```
<div className={ `modal-overlay ${ open ? 'visible' : ''}` }>
    <div 
        ref={ node => (this.modal = node) }
        className={ `modal ${className ? className : ''}` }
    >
        <header>
            <h3>{ title }</h3>
            { !hideCloseButton && 
                <IconButton className="close-button" color="grey" handleClick={ handleClose }>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={ ['far', 'times'] } />
                </IconButton>
            }
        </header>
        <section className="modal-body">
            { children }
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
I've tried to add `evt.stopPropagation()` to deleteChip function, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a simple backdrop:

`<div className="modal-backdrop" onClick={this.props.handleClose}></div>`

This would cover the entire screen you just make sure that the `z-index` in the CSS for the layering is correct. You want to make sure that backdrop is behind the modal body.

Here is one I wrote using `react-transition-group`. Works like a charm for me :)

```
<Transition in={isOpen} timeout={200} unmountOnExit>
    { state => (
      <div className={cn.modalWrapper}>
        <div className={`${cn.modal} modal-${state} ${size}`}>
          <div className={cn.modalBody}>
            { title && 
              <div className={cn.modalTitle}>
                <h3>{title}</h3>
              </div>
            } 
            {children}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={`${cn.modalBackdrop} modal-backdrop-${state}`} onClick={() => handleClose()}></div>
      </div>
    )}
  </Transition>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've modified my modal and used `react-transition-group` ... great tool!